the Variance of the number of a recurrent event in n trials ~ $\frac{\sigma^2}{\mu^3}n$
Let E be a recurrent aperiodic event. Its recurrence time has finite mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Let $N_n$ be the number of occurrences of E in n trials as given, then
$$ E(N_n) \sim \frac{n}{\mu} \space,\space\space Var(N_n) \sim  \frac{\sigma^2}{\mu^3}n$$
I am trying to induce $Var(N_n)$ by using some Generating Functions from my book, but partly succeed it.
$u_n = $ P{E occurs at nth trial}, $f_n = $ P{E occurs for the first time at nth trial} and its GF $U(s), F(s)$ and $U = \frac{1}{1-F}$ , $\mu = F'(1)$
My books(W.Feller) says that (in short)
$$GF(E(N_n)) = \frac{F}{(1-s)(1-F)}, \space\space GF(Var(N_n)) = \frac{F^2+F}{(1-s)(1-F)^2}   $$
$$E(N_n) = [S^n]\left(\frac{F}{(1-s)(1-F)}\right) =\frac{n+1}{\mu}+\frac{\sigma^2-\mu-\mu^2}{2\mu^2}+\epsilon_n \space\space\space(\epsilon_n\to0)$$
$$E(N_n^2) = [S^n]\left(\frac{F^2+F}{(1-s)(1-F)^2}\right) = \frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{\mu^2}+\frac{2\sigma^2-2\mu-\mu^2}{\mu^3}n+\alpha_n \space\space\space(\alpha_n/r\to0)$$
I could get $E(N_n)$(so arduous though), but failed to get $E(N_n^2)$ above.
Can anyone explain How to figure out $E(N_n^2)$?
